# Dificuldade com laço FOR aninhado

Tags: java, loop

Estou criando um código pra desenvolver meus estudos em java e me deram uma idéia/desafio interessante:

Uma pessoa tem 5 cartelas da MegaSena e joga sempre com as mesmas cartelas. Fiz um pequeno código onde se digita os números do último sorteio e ele confere pra ver se bate com as cartelas. Vejam:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {


    int[] cartela1 = {13,25,32,47,59,60};
    int[] cartela2 = {14,26,33,48,55,60};
    int[] cartela3 = {18,63,41,25,21,36};
    int[] cartela4 = {14,26,33,48,55,60};
    int[] cartela5 = {13,25,32,47,59,60};
    int[] numSorteio = new int[6];
    int i,j;
    int count = 0;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (i=0; i<numSorteio.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Digite o número sorteado na posição: " +i);
        numSorteio[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }

    for (i=0; i<6; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<6; j++) {
            if (numSorteio[j] == cartela1[i]) {
                System.out.println("Seu número " + cartela1[i]+ " foi sorteado!");
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Você acertou " +count+ " números na cartela 1!");
}
```

Como podem ver meu código funciona perfeitamente mostrando na saída os números que acertei e a quantidade.

Porém só consegui fazer para a cartela1, se eu repetisse o FOR 5 vezes ficaria perfeito pras 5 cartelas, porém eu queria fazer de forma mais curta e elegante.

Answer (score 2):

Eu fiz da seguinte forma:

1. O mesmo laço for que está fazendo a comparação dos números para a
   primeira cartela pode ser usado para fazer as comparações de todas
   as 5 cartelas como pode ser verificado abaixo
2. Para imprimir o resultado vamos alterar o tipo da variável count,
   que era um inteiro, para vetor, assim podemos armazenar as contagens
   dos acertos de cada cartela em uma posição distinta do vetor (ex:
   posição zero armazena a quantidade de acertos da primeira cartela,
   posição 1 armazena a quantidade de acertos da segunda cartela e
   assim por diante.)
3. Podemos chamar um for para imprimir a quantidade de acerto de cada
   cartela conforme pode ser visto ao final do código.

O codigo ficou assim:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    int[] cartela1 = {13,25,32,47,59,60};
    int[] cartela2 = {14,26,33,48,55,60};
    int[] cartela3 = {18,63,41,25,21,36};
    int[] cartela4 = {14,26,33,48,55,60};
    int[] cartela5 = {13,25,32,47,59,60};
    int[] numSorteio = new int[6];
    int i,j;
    int[] count = new int[5];

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (i=0; i<numSorteio.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Digite o número sorteado na posição: " +i);
        numSorteio[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }

    for (i=0; i<6; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<6; j++) {
            if (numSorteio[j] == cartela1[i]) {
                System.out.println("Seu número " + cartela1[i]+ " foi sorteado na cartela 1!");
                count[0]++;
            }

            if (numSorteio[j] == cartela2[i]) {
                System.out.println("Seu número " + cartela2[i]+ " foi sorteado na cartela 2!");
                count[1]++;
            }

            if (numSorteio[j] == cartela3[i]) {
                System.out.println("Seu número " + cartela3[i]+ " foi sorteado na cartela 3!");
                count[2]++;
            }

            if (numSorteio[j] == cartela4[i]) {
                System.out.println("Seu número " + cartela4[i]+ " foi sorteado na cartela 4!");
                count[3]++;
            }

            if (numSorteio[j] == cartela5[i]) {
                System.out.println("Seu número " + cartela5[i]+ " foi sorteado na cartela 5!");
                count[4]++;
            }
        }
    }

    for(i = 0 ; i<count.length ; i++){
    System.out.println("Você acertou " +count[i]+ " números na cartela "+ (i+1)+"!");

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra opção. Se tiver alguma dúvida, só perguntar. Usei alguns recursos que talvez você ainda não tenha estudado justamente para lhe estimular procurar e saber mais. ;)

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] a = {50, 30, 20, 60, 40, 10};
        int[] b = {21, 10, 38, 40, 50, 22};
        int[] c = {45, 44, 30, 25, 50, 16};
        int[] d = {55, 33, 60, 40, 49, 12};
        int[] numerosSorteados = {10,21,22,38,40,50};

        checarCartelas(numerosSorteados, a, b, c, d);
    }

    //Método tem dois parâmetros: o primeiro sempre será a lista de números sorteados
//O segundo poderá receber N cartelas (isso se chama parâmetro varargs e lhe permite passar
//1, 20, 100 cartelas, quantas quiser)
private static void checarCartelas(int[] numerosSorteados, int[]... cartelas) {
    //Ordena os números sorteados (ordenar simplifica o algoritmo, precisaremos
    //percorrer as cartelas apenas uma vez)
    Arrays.sort(numerosSorteados);

    int numeroDaCartela = 0;

    //Examinamos uma cartela por vez
    for (int[] cartela: cartelas) {

        //Ordenamos a cartela atual
        Arrays.sort(cartela);

        int quantidadeAcertosNaCartela = 0;

        System.out.println("Examinando cartela " + ++numeroDaCartela);

        //Comparamos cada número da cartela atual com cada um dos números sorteados
        for (int i = 0; i < cartela.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cartela.length ; j++) {

                if(cartela[i] == numerosSorteados[j]) {
                    quantidadeAcertosNaCartela++;
                    System.out.println("Seu número " + cartela[i] + " foi sorteado na cartela " + numeroDaCartela);
                }
            }
        }

        if(quantidadeAcertosNaCartela > 0) {
            System.out.println("Parabéns, você teve " +
                    quantidadeAcertosNaCartela +
                    //Usamos um if ternário para que a mensagem
                    // seja gramaticalmente correta (os detalhes importam!!)
                    (quantidadeAcertosNaCartela <= 1 ? " acerto" : " acertos"));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Nenhum número acertado");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Realmente há muita coisa aí que não conheço ainda e não compreendo, mas tô aprendendo. Seu código me tirou o sono nos últimos dias. Depois de muito bater cabeça descobri que há um vício.

Ele só dá match entre um número no array "numerosSorteados" e um número em um dos arrays "A,B,C ou D" se coincidir de os números estarem na mesma posição nos arrays; por exemplo:

ARRAY_CARTELA: {1,19,21,37,48,54}

ARRAY_SORTEIO: {1,18,19,29,44,54}

Os números sorteados que batem são: 01, 19 e 54. O código diz que foram apenas 01 e 54, porque bate a posição nos arrays, mas 19 ele ignora.

Comment: Você tem toda a razão. Ajustei o código e agora deve funcionar sem problemas. Marque a questão como correta se ela atender ao que você precisa.